# Cannot connect to Oracle by SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to connect to my local database by SQL Developer, but *"ORA-28000: the account is locked"* 
occurs.

```
Connection name: HR
Username: HR
Password: HR
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
SID: orcl
```

Oddly enough, when I try to connect by sqlplus, everything is ok:

```
>> sqlplus
>> Enter user-name: HR
>> Enteer password: HR
>> Connected to Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Have you any idea, what is wrong?

Comment: Run this in sqlplus after connecting as `sys`.
 `ALTER USER HR ACCOUNT UNLOCK;`

Comment: OK, I did it and got 'User altered'. But problem still exists.

Comment: Are you getting this error after connecting as SYS?

Comment: I entered: 'sqlplus / as sysdba', and then 'ALTER USER HR ACCOUNT UNLOCK;' and as a result I got 'User altered'. But problem still exists in SQL Developer.

Comment: You are probably connecting to a different Oracle server from SQL*Plus and SQL Developer

Comment: @DavidSilva Close SQL Developer and open again, try to connect to unlocked account.

Answer (score 0):

From your command prompt, type 
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

Once logged in as SYSDBA, you need to unlock the HR account

```
SQL> alter user HR account unlock;
SQL> grant connect, resource to HR;
```

This worked for me.